# AUR and pacman GUI frontend for Arch

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, gui, pacman

Do you know any good GUI for pacman and arch? Where I could view packages installed and possible to install? And of course do anything as in pacman.

Comment: [Checked the Arch Wiki?](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_GUI_Frontends)

Answer (score 3):

While the posted answers are valid, there is actually more than what's listed here. [It appears that there is a of them list on the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_GUI_Frontends) that contains most (If not, all) of the ones available. I'd suggest that you take a look at those and try each one out to see which one suits your needs, and is the one you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think "PackageKit" is the best choise for Gtk's desktop, So for QT you can use "Appset-qt".

Answer (score 0):

pacmanxg  ... https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=125872

Comment: pacmanxg4? It also accesses the AUR repositories.